# Attempting to return a variable from a class returns a function object instead

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm looking to pass a variable out of a class and into another. To do so, I am returning the variable in a method and calling that method in another class. Unfortunately when I do so, all I get is:

```
<function body.returntheline at 0x7f9444673bf8>
```

My code is as follows:

```py
from tkinter import *

class body:

    def __init__(self):

        root = Tk()
        self.input_file = Entry(root)
        self.input_file.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.launch = Button(root, text = "Go External", command = operator)
        self.launch.pack()
        self.launchx= Button(root, text = "GO", command = self.testingvalue)
        self.launchx.pack()
        root.mainloop()

    def testingvalue(self):
        thesillyvalue = self.input_file.get()
        print(thesillyvalue)

    def returntheline(self):
        test = str(self.input_file.get())
        return test

class operator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.textvar = body.returntheline()
        print(self.textvar)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    body()
```

What is it that I have to do to get the specific value from this class instead of the function object? To test that the value does work, I have set up an internal method which does the same thing, only within the class. It does print out a string object to the console, so I am at a loss as to why the returned one does not.

Comment: Quickly going over the question, I suspect you forgot to add `()` to the end of your function call. (I couldn't replicate your error, so that's all I got for you)

Comment: You haven't shown us where you declare an instance of `operator`.  We need to see that.

Comment: Doing so causes the function to execute on calling "body". I'm not looking to do this. This is a TK specific behavior.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's in the line `self.launch = Button(root, text = "Go External", command = operator)`

Comment: @John Gordon Can you please clarify? I don't understand what you are trying to ask for.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.

Comment: The argument `command` should be a function, not a class though.  `operator` is a class.

Comment: I don't see how this code works at all, because `body.returntheline()` is an instance method, and `operator` is referring to the class itself, not a class instance.

Comment: @Idlehands I am looking to call an external class as a button press. This is intentional.

Comment: @John Gordon How would I give it an instance of body to work with? Have I written a code paradox?

Comment: I think @JohnGordon got it.  If you had an instance to pass into `body.returntheline(body_instance)` then it'd work.  Otherwise it returns the bound function IIRC.  Actually just tried it, it gives `TypeError: returntheline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`, so it wouldn't work at all as John suggested.

Comment: @Idlehands Could you provide a sample of code to better illustrate?

Comment: What is the benefit of calling `operator` as an external class over directly calling the instance method? It'd be pretty chaotic to manage the instance in this case.

Comment: @Idlehands Can we focus away from this, in this context all I am trying to do is a proof of concept for something else which is a completely different program where this would make sense. I can't release the other program as it is technically classified material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the instance itself over to the external class via `lambda` or similar:

```
# under class body, change self.launch to this:
self.launch = Button(root, text = "Go External", command = lambda x=self: operator(x))

# Then under class operator:
class operator:

    def __init__(self, body_instance):                 # pass in the instance of body as argument
        self.textvar = body_instance.returntheline()   # directly call the instance method over the instance.
        print(self.textvar)
```

The lambda basically ensures you will always pass `self` (the instance) over to the external class.

But in this case the instance of the external class `operator` is just wasted after calling the `__init__`, but perhaps your real life example have a better use...